# Como obtengo un Select con PDO en Php correctamente

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Estoy intentando obtener un select de una base de datos.

Codigo Index

```
 <?php
                         @$mostrar=$_POST["mostrar"];
                         if($mostrar){
                           $form=1;
                           $mMatricula=$_POST['mMatricula'];
                           sql :: consultar($mMatricula);

                         }

/*Form*/
                         echo"<form action=index.php#contact method=post>";
                         echo"<table id='table2'><tr>";
                         echo"<th><h3>Matricula de Vehiculo a Mostrar</h3></th>";
                         echo"<td><input required type=text name=mMatricula size=20 value=\"".@$mMatricula."\"></td>";
                         echo"<td><input type=submit name=mostrar value=Buscar>";
                         echo"</td></tr>";
                         echo"</table>";
                         echo"</form>";

                         if(@$form>0){
                           echo"<center><form action=index.php#contact method=post>";
                                     echo "<table id='tabla3'> <tr>";
                                                echo "<th>Matricula</th>";
                                                echo "<th>Marca</th>";
                                                echo "<th>Modelo</th>";
                                                echo "<th>Nombre</th>";
                                                echo "<th>Apellido</th>";
                                                echo "<th>Cedula</th>";
                                                echo "<th>Direccion</th>";
                                                echo "<th>Telefono</th>";
                                                echo "<th>Poblacion</th>";

                                           echo "</tr>";
   /*Posible error en el ciclo*/      while(@$row =  mysqli_fetch_array(@$dev)){
                                        echo"<tr>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $row['Matricula'];echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $row['Marca'];echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $row['Modelo'];echo"</td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $row['Nombre'];echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $row['Apellido'];echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $row['Cedula'];echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $row['Direccion'];echo"</td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $row['Telefono'];echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $row['Poblacion'];echo" </td>";

                                        echo"</tr>";
                                    }
                                    echo"</table>";
                                    echo"</form></center>   ";
                         }

                         ?>
```

Codigo pdo sql.php

```
<?php
require 'BaseDatos.php';

class sql
{

  function __construct()
  {
    # code...
  } 
 public static function consultar($mMatricula){
    try {
      $pdo = BaseDatos::obtenerBD()->obtenerConexion();
       $comando ="SELECT * FROM vehiculos WHERE Matricula = ?";
       $sentencia = BaseDatos::obtenerBD()->obtenerConexion()->prepare($comando);
       $sentencia->execute();//Obtiene solo datos no envia
       return $sentencia->fetchAll();


    } catch(PDOException $e) { return $e;}
  }

}
?>
```

Codigo datosconexion.php (por siacaso, esto si corre bien)

```
<?php
define('HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DATABASE', 'transito');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', '');
?>
```

Codigo BaseDatos.php //Igual corre nice

```
<?php require_once 'datosconexion.php';
/**
*
*/
class BaseDatos{
    private static $bd=null;
    private static $pdo;

    function __construct()
    {
        try {
            self::obtenerConexion();
        }catch(PDOException $e) { }
    }

    public static function obtenerBD() {
     if(self::$bd==null) {
        self::$bd = new self();
     }
     return self::$bd;
    }

    public function obtenerConexion() {
         if(self::$pdo==null) {
            self::$pdo= new PDO('mysql:dbname='.DATABASE.';host='.HOSTNAME.';',USERNAME,PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8"));
         self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         }
         return self::$pdo;
    }

    function __destruct() {
        self::$pdo=null;

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: por cierto> ya tengo puesto el require "sql.php"; arriba en el index

Comment: Las preguntas que son básicamente sólo código se consideran de baja calidad, deberías [edit] la pregunta para añadir más detalles: ¿qué es lo que hace ese código? ¿Qué resultado esperas y cuál obtienes? ¿Hay algún mensaje en el log o algún error? ¿Qué has intentado para solucionar el problema? Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Tan simple como
`@$mostrar=$_POST["mostrar"];
                         if($mostrar){
                           $form=1;
                           $mMatricula=$_POST['mMatricula'];
                           $data= sql :: consultar($mMatricula);
                           foreach($data as $key => $value){
                           echo $value["id"];
}
                         }`

Answer (score 0):

Donde se Encuentra la llamada a la clase sql::consultar($mMatricula);

```
 list($mNombre, $mMarca, $mModelo, $mNombre, $mApellido, $mCedula, $mDireccion, $mTelefono, $mPoblacion)= sql :: consultar($mMatricula);
```

Ahora quita el While y agrega las variables puestas en la list

```
  echo"<tr>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $mNombre;echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $mMarca;echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $mModelo;echo"</td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $mNombre;echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $mApellido;echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $mCedula;echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $mDireccion;echo"</td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $mTelefono;echo" </td>";
                                            echo "<td>";echo $mPoblacion;echo" </td>";

                                        echo"</tr>";
```

> fuente [List Manual Php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.list.php)
>   Y el sql.php
>   enviar datos con

```
   $sentencia->execute(array($mMatricula));
```

y retornarlos

> ```
>    return $arr= $sentencia->fetch();
> ```
>
> Fuente [PHP PDO Prepared Statements Tutorial to Prevent SQL Injection](https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection)